# Не работает ЧПУ Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

На сайте создано боковое меню навигации по разделам инфоблока (вложенность больше 4). Подключаю на страницу компонент во включаему область. Проблема в том, что при настройке ЧПУ элемента пропадает боковое меню и футер сайта при переходе на страницу элемента, в то время как на странице со списком элементов всё нормально. При отключённом ЧПУ всё работает корректно. ЧПУ для раздела не настраивается вообще (настраивал по https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=3579). Версия битрикс 16.0.11.

Comment: Настройки ЧПУ делали только в настройках инфоблока или в настройках компонента выводящего элементы тоже? Что прописывается в переменную в которой передается раздел? Приведите скрин настроек ЧПУ из настроек инфоблока и настроек ЧПУ компонента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши вопросы натолкунули на решение. Не было настроену ЧПУ для меню и не правильно было настроено ЧПУ для элементов.